# Drag and Join Div's in a Matrix format

Tags: jquery, html

I am new today in Stackoverflow and this is a first query of mine. So please ask if question is not clear.

I am creating an application where I am using HTML and jQuery. I am creating a Grid in a form of 2*2, 5*5 or 3*8 matrix format. If I want two or more divs inside this matrix to join by dragging one to another and create one div of width of both.

What should be the solution?

Please see below image for more brief example.

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: jQuery Draggable UI. but havnt achieve what i really want.